# Questions about XML semantics

Tags: xml, configuration, semantics

I would like to base a website's configuration on a XML file. I've started to write the following file, but i wonder several things :

```
<config>

    <core>
        <database
            rdbms    = "MySQL"
            name     = "db_name"
            host     = "127.0.0.1"
            login    = "root"
            password = ""
            charset  = "UTF-8"
            engine   = "MyISAM"
        />
        <debug
           log        = "../log.txt"
           models     = "true"
           views      = "true"
           controller = "true"
        />
    </core>

    <application name="app_name">
        <paths>
            <path name="CONTENT_DIR" src="../Content" />
            <path name="LOG_FILE" src="../log.txt" />
        </paths>
        <!-- etc -->
    </application>

</config>
```

- I chose to make database a self closing tag and use attributes to store details about it. I could instead have created a self-closing tag for each of its attribute like `<host value="127.0.0.1" />` and put them in the content of the database tag, but it seemed unlogical as there is only a single host. Database however is a tag since there can be several databases. Does this make sense ? Would there be a clearer/more natural way to do that ?
- What about the debug tag. There should only be a single debug file, but here is it possible to define more than one by adding debug tags. How could i make it a "singleton" ?
- Can i align attributes like i did to make it look cleaner, or is it non standard and should be avoided ?
- More generally : when do you make something an attribute or a tag ?

I think i had more question but they left my mind, so i'll edit my question if they come back :P

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, this is coding related as XML is a computer language, and good practice related too so i don't see any reason why you would want to close this. If you don't want to answer it's fine, just walk away.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel.  There are several open-source configuration management systems out there, including Puppet and Chef.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using the word "tag" to mean "element". An element generally has two tags (a start and an end tag), unless it is empty, in which case it may have a single empty-element tag.

When you "self-closing tag" you should say "empty element". It's quite irrelevant whether the empty element is written as a self-closing tag or as a start-tag/end-tag pair with no content.

Equally, the alignment of attributes is purely decorative, and you should not confuse this with the logical design of the file. As designer of the configuration file format, you have no influence over how authors of actual configuration files choose to do the layout; it's not your problem and you shouldn't care.

The attributes-vs-elements decision is an old chestnut. When you are using XML for document markup there is a genuine distinction (textual content of the document goes in element content, metadata goes in attributes), but when you use XML for structured data, there's no such distintion so it's entirely up to you. When designing a configuration file format for Saxon I made the same decision as you, with extensive use of attributes, but using child elements would work just as well and is perhaps more common. In fact there's an argument that says for data you can do everything with elements, so don't use attributes at all.